# Por que o programa é encerrado antes do scanf

Tags: c

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float a, b, c, delt, c0, c1, c2;
    char s;
    int op = 1;

    printf("Welcome.\n\n");
    while (op == 1) {
        printf("Please type: a, b c.\n\n");

        printf("a:");
        scanf("%f",&a);
        printf("b:");
        scanf("%f",&b);
        printf("c:");
        scanf("%f",&c);

        delt = b*b;
        printf("%c \n",delt);

        printf("Do you want repeat? (y/n)");
        scanf("%c",&s);

        if (s != "y") {
            op = 0;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Por que o último `scanf()` não espera a entrada para seguir com o `if` e decidir se o processo pode ser encerrado?

Estou usando o copilador GNU C Compiler caso seja útil.

Comment: Você está misturando tipos. Se usar aspas ", você está trabalhando com string `char*`, enquanto que com apóstrofo ', o trabalho é feito a nível de caracter `char`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aspas duplas em vez de simples.

> if (s != **"y"**) {
>      op = 0;
>   }

Faça isso:

> if (s != **'y'**) {
>      op = 0;
>   }

Quando quiseres ler um *caractere* podes sempre usar o `getchar()` que é feito especificamente para esse tipo de casos.

Sugiro que mudes o `%c` ali onde imprimes o valor de `del` para `%.2f` ou simplesmente `%f` porque lidas numeros dados do tipo *float*, reais. Para o restante, na parte onde lês o valor de `s` para evitar capturar o valor no `buffer` e invalidar a entrada do *y/n* podes prosseguir como na resposta do @Lucas Martes.

- duplas: *(string)*
- simples: *(char)*

Para declarar variáveis do tipo `bool`, basta que importes a biblioteca, ou podes definir manualmente, usando qualquer um destes exemplos.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0 

typedef enum {true, false} bool;

#import <boolean.h> // já obsoleto nalguns compiladores
```

Depois podes ir usando `bool var` normalmente.

Comment: É possível usar variável boolean ao em vez de int para fazer essa confirmação do loop? Não consigo declará-la estou totalmente acostumado com PHP.

Comment: @ThomsonTorvalds falas da variável `op` ? E o que seria essa variável `delt`, parece mal usada também.

Comment: A delt é para calcular o delta para Bhaskara.
Sim me refiro a op.

Comment: @ThomsonTorvalds sim é possível, mas tens antes de importar um arquivo dependendo do compilador ou so.em uso como vês aí na resposta. Se tiveres qualquer outra questão recomendo que cries outra [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), porque se continuar a editar a resposta, já terá demasiado conteúdo não pertencente a pergunta em questão.

Answer (score 2):

Existe o erro no seu programa que o Edilson comentou, mas ele não resolve o problema do término precoce.
Você deve adicionar um espaço ao seu `scanf` para ignorar a quebra de linha(e também qualquer espaço) que foi gerada antes ao pressionar `ENTER`.
Faça assim:

```
printf("Do you want repeat? (y/n)");
    scanf(" %c",&s);
```

Note o espaço em branco antes do `%c`.

Modifique também:

```
printf("%c \n",delt);
```

por

```
printf("%f \n",delt);
```

Pois delt é do tipo float.